# Fourier Transform for heat equation on a half-plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve heat equation on a half-plane using fourier transform and I don't understand why it doesn't work (yes, I know we can use method of images or sine-transform, but I want to understand why I cannot use this way).
We've got following problem
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}\frac{{\partial \psi}}{{\partial t}} = \frac{{{\partial ^2}\psi}}{{\partial {x^2}}}\\\psi (0,t) = 0\\\psi (x,0) = \delta (a - x)\\x \ge 0,t > 0\end{array} \right.
$$
Extend the task to whole axis and use fourier transform respect to x $$\hat \psi (k,t) = \int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\psi (x,t){e^{ikx}}dx} 
$$
we get
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}\frac{{\partial \hat \psi }}{{\partial t}} =  - {k^2}\hat \psi \\\int\limits_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\hat \psi (k,t)dk}  = 0\\\hat \psi (k,0) = {e^{ika}}\end{array} \right.
$$
The solution of ODE (1) is $$\hat \psi  = C(k){e^{ - {k^2}t}}
$$
and according to (2) it is any odd function
$$C(k) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {{b_n}\sin (nk)} 
$$
but from (3) we've got $C(k) = {e^{ika}}$ and it's contradiction.
I know the right solution and it's
$$f(x,t) = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt {\pi t} }}[{e^{ - \frac{{{{(x - a)}^2}}}{{4t}}}} + {e^{ - \frac{{{{(x + a)}^2}}}{{4t}}}}]
$$
so the right function is $$C(k) = 2i\sin (ka)
$$
and it seems i need to use $$f(x,0) = \delta (a - x) - \delta (a + x)
$$ but it's reflection principle again, and I can't understand why the ordinary method doesn't work (The actual problem why I don't want to use reflection is that I need to solve more difficult task, where we can't use it).

Actually, I heard about Wiener-Hopf method for a half-plane problem, but I cant' understand how to use it for this task, maybe there is some not-so difficult litherature of applying Wiener-Hopf methot to heat equation?